# Using RegexP in Mysql with Pipe/Or

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table which has some address records wrong wherein Street #s to not have "ordinal indicators" (st, rd, th, etc). I made a query with regexp that works if I do

```
Select * from Table where StreetName Regexp '[0-9] St' or StreetName Regexp '[0-9] Ave'
```

I was hoping to make it more efficient by doing

Select * from Table where StreetName Regexp '[0-9] St|Ave|Rd' but that fails. Is there some syntax that will give me what I want i.e. 'Any digit followed by a space and any street suffix'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the `or` parts, otherwise the part that you are `or`ing is unclear.

```
Select * from Table1 where StreetName Regexp '[0-9] (St|ave|rd)'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5a512/1

See: https://regex101.com/r/uZ3rA2/1

vs.

https://regex101.com/r/uZ3rA2/2

Also `[0-9]` is only `0-9` if you want `10` etc. use a quantifier such as `+` or `*` (probably don't want `*` though as that would allow for no numbers as well).